# Проблема с SendKeys

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Возникла необходимость заполнить поля логин и пароль в стандартном `telnet.exe` программно, пытаюсь сделать так:

```
SendKeys.SendWait("ccss_demo" + "{Enter}");
Thread.Sleep(500);
SendKeys.SendWait("ccss_password" + "{Enter}");
```

он у меня заполняет первую строчку

```
SendKeys.SendWait("ccss_demo" + "{Enter}");
```

но вот с таким результатом

> ccssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss

а потом происходит дисконнект.

Как решить проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SetForegroundWindow(process.MainWindowHandle);
SendKeys.SendWait("ccss_demo~");
```